# Compiling X265 on MAC

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation, h.265

I have been trying to compile X265 on mac OS X. I have all prerequisites installed that include CMAKE, YASM 1.3 and Mercurial.

I followed the instruction that were for linux as follows:

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265
$ cd x265/build/linux
$ ./make-Makefiles.bash
$ make
```

and was able to reach to UNIX executable. Then I went into /x265/build/xcode and found a shell script there. Running that script created an XCODE project. I opened the project and tried to build the project. It took it a time but it failed with following error:

```
echo "Creating symlinks"
Creating symlinks
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_symlink_library /Users/Ahmedrik/x265/build/xcode/Debug/libx265.83.dylib /Users/Ahmedrik/x265/build/xcode/Debug/libx265.83.dylib /Users/Ahmedrik/x265/build/xcode/Debug/libx265.dylib
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: No such file or directory
make: *** [x265-shared_buildpart_0] Error 1
```

Can somebody guide me how to acurately compile x265 on Mac installed with Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with `make` in x265/build/linux creates an executable you can use on Mac OSX, so that's really all you need. If you run `./x265` from that directory, you should get the following output:

```
x265 [error]: No input file. Run x265 --help for a list of options.
```